# Getting broker started with django-celery

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

This is my first time using Celery so this might be a really easy question.  I'm following the [tutorial](http://ask.github.com/celery/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html).  I added `BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/"` to my settings file.  I added the simple task to my app.  Now I do "ing the worker process" with

`manage.py celeryd --loglevel=info --settings=settings`

The settings=settings is needed for windows machines [celery-django can't find settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323125/celery--cant-find-settings).

I get 
`[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.   Trying again in 2 seconds...`

So it seems like the worker is not able to connect to the broker.  Do I have to start the broker?  Is it automatically started with `manage.py runserver`?  Do I have to install something besides `django-celery`?  Do I have to do something like `manage.py runserver BROKER_URL`?

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install broker first. Or try to use [django db](http://ask.github.com/celery/getting-started/brokers/django.html#broker-django).

But i do not recommend use django db in production. Redis is ok. But it maybe problem run it on windows.

Comment: Awesome, yeah in the tutorial they don't say to install the Broker.  I guess it obvious but a mention of it would be helpful.  Thanks for the tip about Django DB.  I ended up installing RabbitMQ which worked with Windows.